# Cant set imported dae node into center of screen [SceneKit XCode7.1.1]

Tags: xcode7, scenekit

For learning purposes, I downloaded a .dae file from web. After importing to SceneKit, I cannot set it to the center of the screen.

I tried many positions, and it seemed to have no effect.

Can anybody help me? Thank you very much!

Here is my main code, the whole project can be found in [github](https://github.com/flybywind/Yidingzhi.swift/tree/master/Yidingzhi)

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: properties
    var rotate3D: Rotate3D = Rotate3D(rx: 0, ry: 0, rz: 0)
    var geometryNode: SCNNode!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Nico_Robin.dae")!

        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 300, z: 500)


        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
        lightNode.light!.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

        // retrieve the ship node
        geometryNode = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Nico_Robin", recursively: true)!

        print("girl position:", geometryNode.position)
//        geometryNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z: 0)
//        geometryNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
        // animate the 3d object
//        geometryNode.runAction(SCNAction.repeatActionForever(SCNAction.rotateByX(0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

        // set the scene to the view
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
//        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        // add a tap gesture recognizer
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
        scnView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
//        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
//        scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
```

=====================

Thank God I figured it out, after set `cameraNode.camera?.automaticallyAdjustsZRange = true;` I can see the object and the camera `position` takes effect as expected!

Comment: `cameraNode.camera?.automaticallyAdjustsZRange` is false by default, and default `zFar` is 100. Because my model is large, so after setting camera position.z = 400, you just can't see it.  At first I thought my position is set wrong, now its all clear

Comment: As ridiculous as this sounds, if you answer your own question, those coming along after with the same problem/issue can instantly go from question to answer in the format they know.